# Make NSString equal to label.text?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making a calculator app in Xcode. I need to make the `NSString myLabel` equal to the `calcLabel.text`. This is the current code block I have. I have connected the IBAction to the label.

#### Code:

```
-(IBAction)one:(id)sender{
    NSString *myLabel = @"0";
    NSString *myNumber = @"1";
    calcLabel.text = myLabel;
    if ((calcLabel = 0)) {
        myLabel = @"";
    }
    myLabel = [myLabel stringByAppendingString:myNumber];
    NSLog(@"%@", myLabel);
    calcLabel.text = myLabel;
}
```

Comment: Uh, have you tried `myLabel = Label.text;`?

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Comment: why is 'calcLabel = 0' it should be '[calcLabel.text isEqualString:@""]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`calcLabel = 0` should be `[calcLabel.text isEqualToString:@""]`

Comment: Although that worked, it only outputs "1" on the screen when I press it a few times, It should say "111."

Answer (score 0):

for answer to this line 
it only outputs "1" on the screen when I press it a few times, It should say "111."
try this

```
-(IBAction)one:(id)sender{
    static NSString *myLabel = @"0";
    static NSString *myNumber = @"1";
    calcLabel.text = myLabel;
    if ([calcLabel.text isEqualToString:@"0"]|| [calcLabel.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        myLabel = @"";
    }
    myLabel = [myLabel stringByAppendingString:myNumber];
    NSLog(@"%@", myLabel);
    calcLabel.text = myLabel;
}
```

then if you press 111 then label will show "111" :)

Comment: Nope, it stays the same as was before.

Comment: @shujaAli And how do you suppose that on the next time benr783 calls the one function on a click the myNumber will retain its value?